# Strange command line behaviour when ssh, 7z or cd?

Tags: linux, command-line, password, disk-encryption

I have a very strange behaviour with my remote server. First of all, when I access my server with ssh, I sometimes have to enter my password although my user is in authorized_keys. Sometimes it works without password as expected.

Secondly, I tried to unzip an uploaded file inside my home directory, but this didn't work because I got the following exception:

```
$ 7z x myfile.7z 
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)

Processing archive: myfile.7z

Error: No such file or directory
```

First I thought it has something to do with the file itself and tried to open some files from my Backup directory. As I tried to change into my backup directory, the following happened:

```
$ cd Backup/
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

what the hell is going on here?

Then I logged out and logged in with ssh again (this time I didn't get the password prompt as expected) and suddenly, all these operations work out of the box. Any ideas about this behaviour?

My suspicion is that this has anything to do with the file system encryption of my home folder:

```
/home/.ecryptfs/myself/.Private on /home/myself type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=c98a7ab1a9b19b23,ecryptfs_sig=a7190210385fa1be,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

Comment: Are you the only person who can login as the  `myself` user?

Comment: You have to login with password to decrypt your partition.

Comment: When this happens, are you able to list the contents of the home directory, or even verify that you are in your correct home directory?

Comment: @muru I'm not sure what exactly you mean. In authorized_keys there is only my local user I use to connect to to my remote server. Otherwise, everybody could login who has the password if the prompt appears.

Comment: @MikaelKjær Ok, does this have any effect on the described problems? I mean, can it be that there is something wrong with the decryption process or anything else?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't know it now, but I will test it the next time, the prompt appears. I'm not sure how long I have to wait until this happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. I had the same problem when I used user directory encryption, but never solved it. I switched to full disk encryption instead.

Comment: @Bevor I meant: do other people have the password, and is it likely that they may have logged in around the same time as you? The course of events could happen if: 1. Somebody else (say, Bob) logged in with password, thus mounting the decrypted home folder, 2. you logged in second, and now have access to the decrypted home folder, 3. Bob logs out, and the end of their session causes the decrypted home directory to be unmounted, 4. You're now in the lurch, since any commands you run can no longer access the unmounted directory, 5. Charlie logs in, restarting this loop from 1, and 6. You log in

Comment: @MikaelKjær Ok, thanks fo the information. I will try to figure out if this is somehow solvable.

Comment: @muru No, I'm the only user of my remote server. The only thing is that I'm sometimes logged in with the same account several times.

Comment: @Bevor then the same sequence can still apply, with you as Bob and Charlie, with additional case for 3 that instead of logging out intentionally, the session that caused the decryption got terminated for some other reason.